# how to install LAMP in centos 6.2

Tags: linux, centos, lamp

I'm very new to this thing. I'm trying to install LAMP on centOS 6.2 using `yum -y install php` but I get this error

```
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'"
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

Is there something I have to do before installing??

Answer (score 0):

below error shows your DNS config not work properly.please check internet connectivity

**Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'**

if you can send ping or dig result as below.

```
ping mirrorlist.centos.org

dig mirrorlist.centos.org
```

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, I am using centOS7 but I'll tell you how I fixed it if it helps.

try to edit your network configuration file :

`vi etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

eth0 is the default name but it doesn't always need to be, for example mine is

`vi etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`

note : when you open the file with vi you need to press i (insert mode) to be able to type and eddit.

When you open it you will see few lines with yes - no statements

I eddited `ONBOOT=yes` to `ONBOOT=no`

note : when you're done you need to press ESC to exit the insert mode and type this : `:wq` press enter and save.

You will return to the terminal, from here type `dhclient` press enter and try to start your command again `yum -y install php`

If you receive the same error type `reboot` to restart your system and when it comes back up type again `dhclient` and try again.

At this point it worked for me, hope it will work for you too.